# i am trying to clone multiple fieldset but after clicking it 3 to 4 times next cloned fieldset remains to 4 and 5 number

Tags: javascript, function, clone

i am trying to clone the fieldset as name + 1,2,3 and so on and as well as the inputs id but after cloning one pair of worker compensation fieldset when i click on another fieldset type it gives its input id after the previous cloned fieldset like 4 5 6 as id. i am a novice programmer so plz help me.attached image to understand more and reply me if there is problem.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function cloneit(a,b)
{

        var fieldset = a;
        var fi_class = b;
        //alert(fi_class);

        var count = fi_class.split(/woc_class1/g).length - 1;
        alert(count);

        if(count == 1)
        {
        var newNum = new Number(1);
        }
        else
        {
        var num = $('.cloned').length;
        var newNum = new Number(num + 1);
        }

        var newElem = $(fieldset).clone().attr('id', fieldset + newNum).addClass('cloned');

        $(newElem).css('margin-top','20px');
        //set all div id's and the input id's
        newElem.children('div').each(function(i) {
            this.id = 'input' + (newNum * 5 + i);
        });

        newElem.find('input').each(function() {
            this.id = this.id + newNum;
            this.name = this.name + newNum;

        });

        if (num > 0) {
            $('.cloned:last').after(newElem);
        } else {
            $(fieldset).after(newElem);
        }

        $('#delete').removeAttr('disabled');

        if (newNum == 5) $('#add').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

 }   

function remclone()
    {
        $('.cloned:last').remove();
        $('#add').removeAttr('disabled');
        if ($('.cloned').length == 0) {
            $('#delete').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    }
</script>
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MjYEc.png)

here is the html for it

```
<fieldset id="woc_fieldset">
    <legend>Worker Compensation</legend>
    <table border="0">
    <tr>
    <td>Carier </td>
    <td><input type="text" name="worker_compensation_carrier" id="worker_compensation_carrier" value="<?php echo $a->worker_compensation_carrier; ?>" required="required"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Phone Number</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="worker_compensation_phone" id="worker_compensation_phone" class="phone" value="<?php echo $a->worker_compensation_phone; ?>" required="required"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Premium</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="worker_compensation_premium" id="worker_compensation_premium" value="<?php echo $a->worker_compensation_premium; ?>"  required="required"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Renewal Date</td> 
    <td><input type="text" name="worker_compensation_renewal_date" id="worker_compensation_renewal_date" value="<?php echo $a->worker_compensation_renewal_date; ?>"  required="required"/></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <button type="button" id="delete" onclick="remclone();">Delete</button>
</fieldset>
<button type="button" id="add" onclick="cloneit('#woc_fieldset');">Add</button>



<fieldset id="two">
    <legend>General Liability</legend>
    <table border="0">
    <tr>
    <td>Carier</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="general_liability_carrier" id="general_liability_carrier" value="<?php echo $b->general_liability_carrier; ?>" required="required"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Phone Number</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="general_liability_phone" id="general_liability_phone" value="<?php echo $b->general_liability_phone; ?>" required="required"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Premium</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="general_liability_premium" id="general_liability_premium" value="<?php echo $b->general_liability_premium; ?>"  required="required"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Renewal Date</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="general_liability_renewal_date" id="general_liability_renewal_date" value="<?php echo $b->general_liability_renewal_date; ?>" required="required" /></td>
    </tr>
    </table>

</fieldset>


<fieldset id="three">
    <legend>Group Health</legend>
    <table border="0">
    <tr>
    <td>Carier</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="group_health_carrier" id="group_health_carrier" value="<?php echo $c->group_health_carrier; ?>"  required="required"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Phone Number</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="group_health_phone" id="group_health_phone" value="<?php echo $c->group_health_phone; ?>"  required="required" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Premium</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="group_health_premium" id="group_health_premium" value="<?php echo $c->group_health_premium; ?>"  required="required"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Renewal Date</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="group_health_renewal_date" id="group_health_renewal_date" value="<?php echo $c->group_health_renewal_date; ?>"  required="required"/></td>
    </tr>
    </table>

</fieldset>



<fieldset id="four">
    <legend>Property</legend>
    <table border="0">
    <tr>
    <td>Carier</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="property_carrier" id="property_carrier" value="<?php echo $d->property_carrier; ?>"  required="required"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Phone Number</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="property_phone" id="property_phone" value="<?php echo $d->property_phone; ?>"  required="required"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Premium</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="property_premium" id="property_premium" value="<?php echo $d->property_premium; ?>"  required="required"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Renewal Date</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="property_renewal_date" id="property_renewal_date" value="<?php echo $d->property_renewal_date; ?>"  required="required"/></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</fieldset>


<fieldset id="five">
    <legend>Commercial Auto</legend>
    <table border="0">
    <tr>
    <td>Carier</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="commercial_auto_carrier" id="commercial_auto_carrier" value="<?php echo $e->commercial_auto_carrier; ?>"  required="required"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Phone Number</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="commercial_auto_phone" id="commercial_auto_phone" value="<?php echo $e->commercial_auto_phone; ?>" required="required" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Premium</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="commercial_auto_premium" id="commercial_auto_premium" value="<?php echo $e->commercial_auto_premium; ?>" required="required" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Renewal Date</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="commercial_auto_renewal_date" id="commercial_auto_renewal_date" value="<?php echo $e->commercial_auto_renewal_date; ?>" required="required" /></td>
    </tr>
    </table>

</fieldset>
```

Comment: What's the relevant (minimal/[sscce](http://sscce.org/)) HTML for this problem? Can you [show a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Offtopic: Don't write `new Number(1)`, just write `1`.

Comment: actually after cloneing 2 or 3 fieldset of worker compensation when i click on general liability its id becomes id="name3" or id="name4" instead i want it to intialize to 1 for general liability that is id of general liability id="name1"

Comment: no one to help.please help me to solve this code

Answer (score 0):

```
function cloneit(a,b)
{

        var fieldset = a;
        var fi_class = b;
        alert(fi_class);


        var num = $('.'+fi_class).length;
        alert(num);
        var newNum = new Number((num - 1) +1);


        var newElem = $(fieldset).clone().attr('id', fieldset + newNum);

        $(newElem).css('margin-top','20px');
        //set all div id's and the input id's
        newElem.children('div').each(function(i) {
            this.id = 'input' + (newNum * 5 + i);
        });

        newElem.find('input').each(function() {
            this.id = this.id + newNum;
            this.name = this.name + newNum;

        });

        if (num > 0) {
            $('.'+fi_class+':last').after(newElem);
        } else {
            $(fieldset).after(newElem);
        }

        $('#delete').removeAttr('disabled');

        if (newNum == 5) $('#add').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

 }   

function remclone()
    {
        $('.'+fi_class+':last').remove();
        $('#add').removeAttr('disabled');
        if ($('.cloned').length == 0) {
            $('#delete').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    }
```